# keep having this pop-up "The terminal failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (cannot create process, error code:225)"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently updated my VScode and trying to access Git Bash through my terminal, but I keep receiving the pop-up. Went through the Troubleshoot terminal launch failures... although I have followed some guidelines by configuring the default Profile to PowerShell, I still keep receiving the pop-up. what else can I can do?

Tried the procedures from the help guidelines of VScode.

Comment: is that the _exact_ text of the error message with no typos and exact spelling and capitalization and whitespacing? because if so, you're the first person to post the error message on the public web, and I'd suggest that you also raise an issue ticket using the Help > Raise Issue menu bar action and then post here the link to your issue ticket.